# React Native Expo map

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I Have a map marker that is centered on the current user location.
This marker has a draggable property so it it possible to drag
the marker around on the map. My questions is how can i set the current region prop
of the map onDragEnd of the maker. I basically want the user to be able to 
drag the marker around and update the map region.

```
 region={{ latitude: this.state.region.latitude, longitude: this.state.region.longitude, latitudeDelta: 0.0922, longitudeDelta: 0.0421 }}
                     showsUserLocation={true} loadingEnabled={true}  followsUserLocation={false}>
                    <MapView.Marker

                    onDragEnd={this.onRegionChange(this.state.region)}
```

//On region change method that gets fires ondragEnd of the marker

```
onRegionChange=(region) => {
      this.setState({region
       });
      console.log(this.state.region)
    }
```

Comment: Hey, I too would like to know this. Did you get it working?

Comment: Yes i did manage to get this working. Solution is to call a method onDragEnd of the marker to update the region state of the map.

Comment: @GraigPeru Could you show us how you did it?